# Change bootstrap form based on the users active input. Display a change in the form only based on the text entered and no button clicks

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js, twitter-bootstrap-3

Like credit card logo pops up as you enter in your credit card number. Instead of a logo I want to display a change in the form without a button click. Form automatically detects change after the input field has been filled.

Comment: Hello Terrence, welcome to SO ! Don't hesitate to take a look on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) documentation. It may help you create better question that could help other people having the same problem. You will also probably answered faster and more accurately.

Answer (score 0):

Simple example:

In Angularjs

```js
$scope.changeStyle=function(){
$scope.color="red";
}
```

```html
    <form>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" ng-model="someName" ng-change="changeStyle()" id="exampleInputEmail1" ng-style="{'color':color}"
      placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
   </form>
```